# Login Password for class

Tags: android

This is the code for a login setup, in order to enter the Setting page. onClickView shows an error, it must be implemented in Setting class. Any suggestions or solutions?

```
public class Setting1 extends Settings  implements OnClickListener{

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pass_set);
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordedittext);
    Button buttonEnter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sumbitbutton);
    buttonEnter.setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCLick(View v){
    EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordedittext);
    String password = et.getText().toString();
    et.getEditableText().toString();
    if(password.equals("Password")){
      Intent intent = new Intent(Setting1.this, Settings.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
    else{
      AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
      builder.setTitle("YOU SUCK!"); 
      builder.setMessage("Try Again!"); 
      builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null); 
      AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `onCLick` is mispelled. It should be `onClick` (lowercase l)

Comment: A lesson to learn TODAY - do not use harshly negative/inflammatory strings in your development.  Someday, when you release, you will discover that some of this verbiage was not caught and makes it to your customer. You will not enjoy this day.

Comment: define "onClickView shows an error"

Comment: It's a typo. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196985/232821

Answer (score 0):

As *@A--C* already pointed out in the comments,

```
public void onClick(View v){
.
.
.    
    }
```

You spelt **`onClick`** wrong (your code has *onCLick*).